# divi builder @media command

Tags: css, media, builder

I am currently using DIVI Builder to build a simple website. 
I have a fullwidth section, with a full width slider inside. The text inside the slider seems to behave differently on desktop versus mobile, so I figured i can help that with @media. What i have done so far is to create a duplicate, identical slide, adjust the 2nd of the two for mobile and hide the 2nd from desktop users. While I don't exactly know, I assume that this way will eventually slow down the page loading speed, so I resorted to @media.

The issue preventing this from working is that the media inquiry starts with:

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
   XXX {
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
 }
```

The XXX represents the unknown for me, because I want to target the whole column, in this case automatically labeled as `.et_pb_slide_0`. From what I understand i cannot replace the XXX with a class, or in other words, something that starts with a `.` Is there any way to make this work ??

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can contain classes like `.et_pb_slide_0` or `.anything_you_like`!

This is valid:

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
    .et_pb_slide_0 {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}
```